# Keeping values selected after form submission with php

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to keep selected values after form submission, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246244/1354580) by @ignacio-vazquez-abrams. I tried this:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    ...
    foreach ($file_array as $location)
        $options .= '<option name="' . $location . (($_GET['name'] == $location) ? 'selected="true"' : '') . '" value="' . $location . '">' . $location .'</option>';
    $select = '<select id="location" name="location">' . $options . '</select>';
    echo $select;
    ...
</form>
```

but I got a notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in ...

**UPDATE**

Than I tried this (as was suggested in comments and I how is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/1354580)):

```
$options .= '<option name="' . $location . (!isset($_GET['selected']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '" value="' . $location . '">' . $location .'</option>';
```

with no errors, but the expected result still has not been produced - selected values after form submission are not retained.

How to achieve this?

Comment: how does you form tag look like? `method="post"` or `method="get"`

Comment: `name=` should be `selected=`

Comment: Its throwing an error for `Undefined index: name` so check are you getting value within `$_GET` also `name` attribute is not for `option` but its for `select`

Comment: @swidmann I updated the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @hasan-fathi I updated the question and I explained why it isn't a duplicate. Thanks for the link, it was helpful for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole lot missing to actually adding a right answer for this, but i'll try anyway.

PHP locations array:

```
$locations = array( 'Loc1', 'Loc2', 'Loc3' );
```

On the form:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="location">
        <?php 
            foreach ( $locations as $location ) {
                echo '<option value="' . $location . '" ' . ( isset( $_GET['location'] ) && $_GET['location'] == $location ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' . $location . '</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

First of all there's no way of telling that your posted value is the value `name`. As i recall there's no name attribute for option, it has to be a select around it which holds the attribute name, and you are putting the `selected="true"` in the name attribute which you are not properly closing in the first place (and which is non existing).

Comment: Sorry! I updated the question with the missing data, but you guessed it anyway. In the future questions I will be more careful and I will include all necessary information. Now the code is working as was expected! Thank you very much?

Comment: another approach using `js` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458797/4050261

Answer (score 1):

You are using a strict mode of PHP, therefore you need to check if the GET param is passed (by using `isset()`) before comparing its value to something.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <select id="location" name="location">
        <?php foreach($file_locations as $location): ?>    
        <option <?php echo ((isset($_GET['location']) && $_GET['location'] == $location) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?> value="<?php echo $location ?>"><?php echo $location ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Also you need to write `selected="selected"` or just `selected` instead of `selected="true"`.